# Find IP address and validate which subnet it is in

Tags: bash, ip

We have 3 buildings and I would like to identify the IP that a computer has and then identify which subnet it is in using a series of if/else statements.

For example:

- Building 1 = 192.168.1.1 /24
- Building 2 = 192.168.2.1 /24
- Building 3 = 192.168.3.1 /24

I think I've figured out how to identify the computers IP, now I just need a bit of help figuring out how to change an IP address into a number that can be evaluated. This is what I have so far, but I am missing how to convert the IP somehow.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=192.168.1.20

building1min=192.168.1.1
building1max=192.168.1.255

building2min=192.168.2.1
building2max=192.168.2.255

building3min=192.168.3.1
building3max=192.168.3.255

if [ $ip -lt $building1max && $ip -gt $building1min ]{
    echo "User is in Building 1"
} else if [ $ip -lt $building2max && $ip -gt $building2min ]
    echo "User is in Building 2"
} else if [ $ip -lt $building3max && $ip -gt $building3min ]{
    echo "User is in Building 3"
} else {
    echo "User is not in any building"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should point you in the right direction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

binary=( {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1} )

convertToBinary() {
    local -a oct
    local o res ip=$1 mask=$2 

    IFS=. read -ra oct <<< "$ip"
    for o in "${oct[@]}"; do
        res+=${binary[o]}
    done

    printf '%s\n' "${res:0:mask}"
}

isInSubnet() {
    local sub=$1 ip=$2
    local sub_ip=${sub%/*} sub_mask=${sub#*/}

    [[ $(convertToBinary "$sub_ip" "$sub_mask") = "$(convertToBinary "$ip" "$sub_mask")" ]]
}

# USAGE

ip=192.168.2.15
b1=192.168.1.0/24 b2=192.168.2.0/24

if isInSubnet "$b1" "$ip"; then
    echo building 1
elif isInSubnet "$b2" "$ip"; then
    echo building 2
fi
```

It first converts the IPs to binary and extracts only the network addresses that are then checked for equality.

Comment: Thank you for this! I did a test and at the top put set an IP variable. IP=192.168.2.15 as an example would fall in building 2, but no matter what I put, it always thinks it's in building 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dan I edited my code to demonstrate how to use the `isInSubnet` function with variables.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!